# Unable to render Jsonresult on view AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I am trying to render a json result from my angular controller in a view. But i am failing to do so. i need to show list of names present in the service. if i write like {{menu[0].name}} i get one result but i need to show a list of names

html

```
        <table>
         <tr ng-repeat="menu in MenuAnshu">
        <td>

        {{menu.name}}
    <  /td>
</tr>
```

below is my controller code:

```
         (function () {
var EmployeesController = function ($scope, employeeService, $log) {
    var employees = function (data) {
        $scope.Employees = data;

    };

    var MenuAnshuData = function (data) {
        $scope.MenuAnshu = data;
       console.log(data)
    };

    var errorDetails = function (serviceResp) {
        $scope.Error = "Something went wrong ??";
    };
    employeeService.employees().then(employees, errorDetails);
    employeeService.MenuAnshuData().then(MenuAnshuData, errorDetails);
    $scope.Title = "Employee Details Page";
    $scope.EmployeeName = null;
};

app.controller("EmployeesController", ["$scope", "employeeService", "$log", EmployeesController]);
```

}());

From service i am getting data like this

```
            (function () {
var employeeService = function ($http) {
    var employees = function () {
        return $http.get("http://localhost:63352/api/ptemployees")
                    .then(function (serviceResp) {
                        return serviceResp.data;
                    });
    };

    var MenuAnshuData = function () {
        return $http.get("http://redshaft.in/ocapi/index.php?route=api/order/getcategories").then(function (serviceResp) {
            return serviceResp.data;
        });


    };
    return {
        employees: employees,           
        MenuAnshuData: MenuAnshuData

    };
};

var module = angular.module("ProjectTrackingModule");
module.factory("employeeService", ['$http', employeeService]);
```

}());

i feel i am doing something wrong on js side. I am trying to access the array by menu.name but controller data is an object which has array.

JSON result which i have on controller side

```
               {"categories":[{"category_id":"20","image":"catalog\/demo\/compaq_presario.jpg","parent_id":"0","top":"1","column":"1","sort_order":"1","status":"1","date_added":"2009-01-05 21:49:43","date_modified":"2011-07-16 02:14:42","language_id":"1","name":"Desktops","description":"&lt;p&gt;\r\n\tExample of category description text&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n","meta_title":"","meta_description":"Example of category description","meta_keyword":"","store_id":"0"},{"category_id":"18","image":"catalog\/demo\/hp_2.jpg","parent_id":"0","top":"1","column":"0","sort_order":"2","status":"1","date_added":"2009-01-05 21:49:15","date_modified":"2011-05-30 12:13:55","language_id":"1","name":"Laptops &amp; Notebooks","description":"&lt;p&gt;\r\n\tShop Laptop feature only the best laptop deals on the market. By comparing laptop deals from the likes of PC World, Comet, Dixons, The Link and Carphone Warehouse, Shop Laptop has the most comprehensive selection of laptops on the internet. At Shop Laptop, we pride ourselves on offering customers the very best laptop deals. From refurbished laptops to netbooks, Shop Laptop ensures that every laptop - in every colour, style, size and technical spec - is featured on the site at the lowest possible price.&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n","meta_title":"","meta_description":"","meta_keyword":"","store_id":"0"},{"category_id":"25","image":"","parent_id":"0","top":"1","column":"1","sort_order":"3","status":"1","date_added":"2009-01-31 01:04:25","date_modified":"2011-05-30 12:14:55","language_id":"1","name":"Components","description":"","meta_title":"","meta_description":"","meta_keyword":"","store_id":"0"},{"category_id":"57","image":"","parent_id":"0","top":"1","column":"1","sort_order":"3","status":"1","date_added":"2011-04-26 08:53:16","date_modified":"2011-05-30 12:15:05","language_id":"1","name":"Tablets","description":"","meta_title":"","meta_description":"","meta_keyword":"","store_id":"0"},{"category_id":"17","image":"","parent_id":"0","top":"1","column":"1","sort_order":"4","status":"1","date_added":"2009-01-03 21:08:57","date_modified":"2011-05-30 12:15:11","language_id":"1","name":"Software","description":"","meta_title":"","meta_description":"","meta_keyword":"","store_id":"0"},{"category_id":"24","image":"","parent_id":"0","top":"1","column":"1","sort_order":"5","status":"1","date_added":"2009-01-20 02:36:26","date_modified":"2011-05-30 12:15:18","language_id":"1","name":"Phones &amp; PDAs","description":"","meta_title":"","meta_description":"","meta_keyword":"","store_id":"0"},{"category_id":"33","image":"","parent_id":"0","top":"1","column":"1","sort_order":"6","status":"1","date_added":"2009-02-03 14:17:55","date_modified":"2011-05-30 12:15:25","language_id":"1","name":"Cameras","description":"","meta_title":"","meta_description":"","meta_keyword":"","store_id":"0"},{"category_id":"34","image":"catalog\/demo\/ipod_touch_4.jpg","parent_id":"0","top":"1","column":"4","sort_order":"7","status":"1","date_added":"2009-02-03 14:18:11","date_modified":"2011-05-30 12:15:31","language_id":"1","name":"MP3 Players","description":"&lt;p&gt;\r\n\tShop Laptop feature only the best laptop deals on the market. By comparing laptop deals from the likes of PC World, Comet, Dixons, The Link and Carphone Warehouse, Shop Laptop has the most comprehensive selection of laptops on the internet. At Shop Laptop, we pride ourselves on offering customers the very best laptop deals. From refurbished laptops to netbooks, Shop Laptop ensures that every laptop - in every colour, style, size and technical spec - is featured on the site at the lowest possible price.&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n","meta_title":"","meta_description":"","meta_keyword":"","store_id":"0"}]}
```

My problem is i am not able to render list of names using {{menu.names}} on view. What i need to do to get the list of names on view?

Comment: Show us your controller code where you are populating variable `MenuAnshu`

Comment: Please add your controller code

Comment: Try to display the contents of `MenuAnshu` in your view like so: `<pre>{{MenuAnshu | json}}</pre>`. If this does not contain any data then this variable has not been populated with any data in your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not easily readable.

I suggest you return the promise from your service to your controller and then resolve it like so:

```
// service
// return the promise of the GET request
var MenuAnshuData = function () {
    return $http.get("http://redshaft.in/ocapi/index.php?route=api/order/getcategories");
};

// controller
// make the call to MenuAnshuData from your service 
employeeService.MenuAnshuData().then(function(response) {

    // log the data so you can inspect what you have
    console.log(response.data)

    // pouplate MenuAnshu with the response
    $scope.MenuAnshu = data;

}, function(error) {

    // handle any failed response 

});
```

Comment: i have restructed the code. i tried ur code . in console i get op like this :Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
config
:
Object
data
:
Object
categories
:
Array[8]
0
:
Object
category_id
:
"20"      how can i render this on the view.. by using the code i have written in html i cant achieve the desired result,

Comment: i get this response Object {categories: Array[8]}
categories
:
Array[8]
0
:
Object
category_id
:
"20"
column
:
"1"
date_added
:
"2009-01-05 21:49:43"
date_modified
:
"2011-07-16 02:14:42"
description
:
"&lt;p&gt;
↵ Example of category description text&lt;/p&gt;
↵"
image
:
"catalog/demo/compaq_presario.jpg"
language_id
:
"1"
meta_description
:
"Example of category description"
meta_keyword
:
""
meta_title
:
""
name
:
"Desktops" in console...

Comment: my problem is how to render these list of names in view.. if i use a ng-repeat  menu in menusnahsu and do {{menu.name}} or  {{ menu.category.name}} i dont get the list of names in the view. if i do {{menu[0].name}} i do get one name though

Comment: If you want to repeat your categories then use `ng-repeat="menu in MenuAnshu.categories"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want iterate over objects in angular js you have to do the following statement:

```
Ng-repeat="(key,value) in object"
```

Try that, I have seen that URL retrieve json object in first moment then I think can works.

comment the results !

Comment: can u elaborate on that... not sure how to use (key, value) in my $scope object

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with this line:
`employeeService.MenuAnshuData().then(MenuAnshuData, errorDetails);`

You can update your service as below:

```
var MenuAnshuData = function () {
    var config = {method: 'GET', url:"http://redshaft.in/ocapi/index.php?route=api/order/getcategories"}
    return $http(config);
};
```

And then access the promise's `get` method in your controller:

```
employeeService.MenuAnshuData().then(MenuAnshuData, errorDetails);
```

Comment: tried this gives me this errorangular.js:12722 Error: [$http:badreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$http/badreq?p0=http%3A%2F%2Fredshaft.in%2Focapi%2Findex.php%3Froute%3Dapi%2Forder%2Fgetcategories

Comment: it gives me this json Object
categories
:
Array[8]
0
:
Object
category_id
:
"20"
column
:
"1"
date_added
:
"2009-01-05 21:49:43"
date_modified
:
"2011-07-16 02:14:42"

Comment: but i m not able to render list of names on ui . using the code i have written. My problem is rendering of names on the ui..

Comment: You're not able to render the names because there's issue with the data object. While your HTML seems perfectly fine, you could try using `$parent.menuAnshu` in HTML instead of `menuAnshu`. Also, please provide the JSON response so that it may help in debugging your problem.

Comment: i used $parent,menuanshu it  is not working. i have updated the problem with json response

Comment: As evident in your update, you needed to iterate over `menuAnshu.categories` and not just `menuAnshu`. Glad that you found the solution.